How to find the general form of a vector acted upon by linear and non linear operations
I stumbled upon this problem, originally I considered it easy to solve, I tried, and failed, and now I am beginning to believe it is quite a formidable adversary; so I am posting here, in hope of getting some help.
Consider a real square matrix $A$, made of smaller square matrices of two kinds: $\mathcal{A_{ij}}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{i}$; specifically the matrix should have the following structure:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{B}_1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\mathcal{A}_{21} & \mathcal{B}_2 & 0 & 0\\
\mathcal{A}_{31} & \mathcal{A}_{32} & \mathcal{B}_3 & 0\\
\mathcal{A}_{41} & \mathcal{A}_{42} & \mathcal{A}_{43} & \mathcal{B}_4
\end{pmatrix}_{N\times N}$$
Suppose I multiply this matrix for a vector $\vec{a}$ that has only the top elements not equal to zero
$$\vec{a}=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{x}\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
I would get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{B}_1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\mathcal{A}_{21} & \mathcal{B}_2 & 0 & 0\\
\mathcal{A}_{31} & \mathcal{A}_{32} & \mathcal{B}_3 & 0\\
\mathcal{A}_{41} & \mathcal{A}_{42} & \mathcal{A}_{43} & \mathcal{B}_4
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{x}\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{B}_1\cdot\vec{x}\\
\mathcal{A}_{21}\cdot\vec{x}\\
\mathcal{A}_{31}\cdot\vec{x}\\
\mathcal{A}_{41}\cdot\vec{x}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So far so good. But suppose now to apply after the matrix multiplication a non linear function $F: \mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}^N$ such that:
$$F\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\ \vdots\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}f(a)\\f(b)\\ \vdots\end{pmatrix}$$
where $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is another non linear function.
So:
$$F \circ A\vec{a} = F(A\vec{a})=\begin{pmatrix}
F(\mathcal{B}_1\cdot\vec{x})\\
F(\mathcal{A}_{21}\cdot\vec{x})\\
F(\mathcal{A}_{31}\cdot\vec{x})\\
F(\mathcal{A}_{41}\cdot\vec{x})
\end{pmatrix} \equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{y}_1(1)\\
\vec{y}_2(1)\\
\vec{y}_3(1)\\
\vec{y}_4(1)
\end{pmatrix} \tag{1}
$$
But I am not really interested in the vector (1), I am interested in what I get for $\vec{y}_4$ after I repeat the prodedure $3$ times, so:
$$[F\circ A \circ F \circ A\circ F \circ A](\vec{a})=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{y}_1(3)\\
\vec{y}_2(3)\\
\vec{y}_3(3)\\
\vec{y}_4(3)
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ , \ \ \ \vec{y}_4(3)=?$$
And in general I am interested in the case of a matrix $N \times N$ made of $B\times B$ blocks, and I want to understand what happens to $\vec{y}_B(B-1)$ at the end of the operation!
My question is: is there some way of expressing the value of $\vec{y}_B(B-1)$ in the general case as an expression of the smaller matrices and $\vec{x}$? I have tried to come up with a formula for $\vec{y}_B(B)$ that holds for all $B$ but I have failed.

Edit: My attempt at a solution:
The final output is the result of the $B$ blocks in the last row, so maybe it makes sense to divide the problem into $B$ additions; the first block $\mathcal{A}_{B1}$ in the end should give the contribution:
$$F \circ \mathcal{A}_{B,1}\circ \left[\overset{B-3}{\underset{i=1}\bigcirc}\ F \circ \mathcal{B}_1\right] \circ F \circ \mathcal{B}_1 \vec{x}$$
or something similar; the second block should insted give something like:
$$F \circ \mathcal{A}_{B,2} \circ \left\{\sum \bigcirc \left[ \left(F \circ \mathcal{A}_{2,1}\right) \circ \left(F \circ \mathcal{B}_2 \right) \circ \left(F \circ \mathcal{B}_1 \right) \right]\right\} \circ F \circ\mathcal{B}_1\vec{x}$$
The problem is that I cannot understand the order and the number of combinations for the sum of composition in the center, and I imagine it will get only worse for the other contributions..
